# inquirer package with CDK VSCode debug

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code, aws-cdk

I have created a CDK script in Typescript. The script uses [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) v9.2.0 *(ESM module)*. The script also uses [@aws-sdk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) v3. I can't seem to get the correct configuration with my launch.json & tsconfig.json. The configs that are out of the box are:

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "cdk.out"
  ]
}
```

I also do **not** set `type` to be "module" in my package.json *(as this causes issues with CDK & SDK imports)*. It might be required to do inquirer.js due to specifying that .js files use ESM modules but it breaks due to all of my other files being .ts files.

**launch.json**

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Program (JS)",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/bin/cdk-bootstrap-account.js",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "node",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "type": "node"
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program (TS)",
            "skipFiles": [
                "<node_internals>/**"
            ],
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "-r",
                "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/ts-node/register"
            ],
            "args": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/bin/cdk-bootstrap-account.ts"
            ],
            "runtimeExecutable": "node"
        }
    ]
}
```

If I try to run "Launch Program (TS)" with that current configuration, I get:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /node_modules/inquirer/lib/inquirer.js from /bin/cdk-bootstrap-account.ts not supported.
> Instead change the require of inquirer.js in /bin/cdk-bootstrap-account.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

Setting `moduleResolution` to "nodenext" still doesn't fix the issue. Is the only possible way to transpile all my typescript into javascript & use source maps to debug?

However, if I run `tsc` to build the project & try to run "Launch Program (JS)" - if I don't have `type` as "module" in the package.json then it's the same inquirer error *(just thrown from a transpiled .js file instead)* & the error:

> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

For reference, my `bin/cdk-bootstrap-account.ts` is:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
import 'source-map-support/register';
import { ensureEnv } from "@pimberly/png-lib-core";
import { request } from "urllib"
import { EC2Client, DescribeAvailabilityZonesCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ec2"
import { Netmask } from "netmask"
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { CdkBootstrapAccountStack } from '../lib/cdk-bootstrap-account-stack';
import inquirer from "inquirer";
import { ISubnetNumbers, IBaseSubnets } from "../interfaces"
import { getChosenSubnetNumber, getSubnetCidrBlocks, getVPCCidrBlock, getSubnetAvailabilityZones } from "../src/helpers"

const app = new cdk.App();

/* For more information, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/environments.html */
async function main() {
  const response = inquirer.prompt([
      {
        type: 'input',
        name: 'public',
        message: `How many subnets do you want to create? (default: 2 - max: 3)`,
        default: 2,
        validate(value: string) {
          const parsed = parseInt(value)

          return parsed >= 2 && parsed <= 3
        },
        transformer(value: any) {
          return parseInt(value)
        }
      }
  ])
  ...
}
main()
```

What's the best way to go about this?